# return final result from recursive function with promises

Tags: javascript, promise

a have a little problem with recursive function that return promises:

function like this:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
    }, 500);

});

let count = 1;
const recursiveWithPromise = () => {
    return promise.then(result => {
        count += 1
        if (count !== 10) {
            return recursiveWithPromise();
        }
        if (count === 10) {
            return 'finalResult'
        }
    });
}

let a = recursiveWithPromise()
```

I want to save only finalResult in some variable, but if i save it like this:

`const someVar = recursiveWithPromise(params)`  or `const someVar = recursiveWithPromise(params).then(res => res)`  it was undefined. So how i can get my finalResult ?

Comment: @Unmitigated i can't use await because it returns undefined first value, because it is the fasted return value (when nothing to do) there are many async functions calls, but i need only finalValue

Comment: Hint: Missing a return in  `if(!finished)` which is why you get `undefined`

Comment: …and also in case of `someCases` you return nothing.

Comment: Even assuming you meant `count == 3` not `count = 3`, your counter never reaches 10 and your function never reaches the `return 'finalResult'` line. So what do you expect the `a` promise to fulfill with?

Comment: It would help if you could post your actual code, not some contrived example.

Comment: @Bergi thx i fix my error. But this code is simple to test and understand. Еhe structure is same, just in some cases we have we have duplicate parameters nd we want to skip complex calculations.

Comment: @dendroid And when you're "skipping complex calculations", what do you want the function to return? Currently it returns `undefined`, that is indeed simple to understand.

Comment: @dendroid Thanks for the update, but the recursion still stops at `count === 5` and results in `undefined` - `return 'finalResult'` is never executed.

Comment: @Bergi sorry I was in a hurry, fix it

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, but now your code works. It returns a promise that will be fulfilled with `'finalResult'`, just as expected. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not returning the result of the recursive call. If you do, the last frame result will be returned back and forth to the first frame and will eventually get you the desired result:

```
return recursive(newParams);
```

Indeed, the return value of a `Promise` callback can either be a bare value, or a `Promise` which is automatically being unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using global state, especially with asynchronous programs. Instead write functions that accept arguments and return values -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

function count(n) {
  console.log(n)
  if (n >= 10)
    return "done"
  else
    return sleep(1000).then(_ => count(n + 1))
}

count(0).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
0
1
2
...
9
10
done
```

The beauty of `async`/`await` is that your asynchronous programs can look/feel nearly identical to their synchronous counterparts -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function count(n) {
  console.log(n)
  if (n >= 10) return "done"
  await sleep(1000)
  return count(n + 1)
}

count(0).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
0
1
2
...
9
10
done
```

If your recursive function expects a promise as input, the program changes slightly -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

function count(p) {
  return p.then(n => {
    console.log(n)
    if (n >= 10)
      return "done"
    else
      return count(sleep(1000).then(_ => n + 1))
  })
}

count(Promise.resolve(0)).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
0
1
2
...
9
10
done
```

Again, using `async` and `await` improves the readability of the program significantly -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function count(p) {
  const n = await p
  console.log(n)
  if (n >= 10) return "done"
  await sleep(1000)
  return count(n + 1)
}

count(Promise.resolve(0)).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
0
1
2
...
9
10
done
```